# Can common tablespace created in Oracle CDB accessed across all PDBs?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, multi-tenant, tablespace

I want to `FLASHBACK ARCHIVE` a table in different PDBs. I want to create a separate tablespace for the purpose of flashback archiving. I was going through Oracle docs about CDB (Container database) and PDB (Pluggable database). I found that a common user can be created who is accessible from all the PDBs and CDB. I was wondering whether a common tablespace can be created in Oracle CDB which is accessible across all PDBs, by this common user? And a `FLASHBACK ARCHIVE` for each PDB which uses the common tablespace created in CDB so that the common user archives into the respective flashback archives in its PDB and each flashback archive is invisible to the user in other PDB.

Or, a separate tablespace is to be created in each and every PDB for FLASHBACK ARCHIVE?

Example: Assume there is an EMPLOYEES table in 2 different PDBs PDB1 and PDB2. What is the best way to archive EMPLOYEES table time-to-time, without the users in other PDBs knowing, and with less effort?

A common user HR is present. I want HR from PDB1 and PDB2 to archive EMPLOYEES table of respective PDBs into a common `TABLESPACE` FLASH_TABLSPACE, if possible. (Or any better alternative for the same)

Answer (score 0):

To begin with the [multi-tenant architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234) (CDB having multiple PDBs) allows separation of concerns (SoC). Where each PDB is on its own and doesn't depend on any other PDB for its functioning. This ensures that one PDB can't see what's happening in another PDB. The ROOT Container (CDB) manages the PDBs at a higher level (memory, plug-in, plug-out etc.,).

Coming to your requirement, the Flashback Data Archive can be created in each PDB. We don't need to create a tablespace in CDB (ROOT) that's not the way the multi-tenant is envisioned. Each PDB is a fully functioning database, so we can create the tablespace required for Flashback Data Archive in PDB itself. The Flashback Data Archive can be created in PDB either using system supplied common user (SYS,SYSTEM) or using dba supplied common user (C##...).